# MokManager not found and Secure Boot forbids loading module from (hd0)/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/*

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, security

This question is probably related to [my question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156196/why-is-the-ubuntu-installers-filesystem-unknown-in-ubuntu-itself). This is for a laptop that has UEFI and secure boot.

Background:
**1. Clonezilla:** I've been able to take a backup (and restore) from a laptop using CloneZilla installed on a USB earlier, but when I tried creating a CloneZilla USB again, the "mmx64.efi" not being found error kept showing up, and if I [renamed/copied the grub64.efi in the CloneZilla USB file to mmx64.efi](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1798171), CloneZilla's initial screen would start, but then it'd say that it could not find the kernel and there was no way forward from that screen. Also, earlier I could run VirtualBox even with secure boot enabled. Now it works only if secure boot is disabled.
**2. Secure boot changes:** So assuming the [problem was with not having run the mokmanager](https://askubuntu.com/a/1126422/148011) after Ubuntu installation, I went to BIOS and marked `mmx64.efi` of the Ubuntu dual boot partition as trusted. On rebooting I was taken to the MokManager screen where I think I disabled secure boot (but secure boot was still shown as 'Enabled' in BIOS).
**3. Full disk wipe:** Now on booting with the Ubuntu 16.04 installer USB, a message saying 'Booting in insecure mode' starts showing up (image below), so I use `dd` to erase the first 1MB of the hard disk, I wipe the entire disk with zeros using `dd`, I reset BIOS to factory defaults, clear all trusted secure boot settings and reinstall Windows 8.1. Windows boots fine, but when I try booting with the Ubuntu USB, I'm first shown the errors as in the image below, and only then the Ubuntu grub menu is shown.
[image]

**Question:**
Is the laptop compromised? Why is it booting in `insecure mode`? Why is it still searching for MokManager and why is secure boot forbidding loading of certain modules? Is this a problem with only the Ubuntu bootable USB? For this laptop I need to continue using 16.04 (can't use 18.04 since it consumes too much RAM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution here: http://nrecursions.blogspot.com/2019/08/solving-mokmanager-mmx64efi-not-found.html
Rename grubx64.efi to mmx64.efi. Problem is, Ubuntu shows you a totally different filesystem. In Windows, you won't be able to see all the files in the pen drive. It just shows you one folder into which you have to navigate into, find the grubx64.efi file and rename it to mmx64.efi. You'll now be able to boot from the pen drive. After installing Ubuntu, you have to rename that file on the pen drive back to grubx64.efi (and you have to do it in Windows; not in Ubuntu), or else you won't be able to boot from the pen drive.
This just seems to be a case of bad compatibility and needs to be fixed by either the OEM or by the Ubuntu community.